# Compare values in 1 column in CSV file with MySQL values in 1 column and delete in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, compare

I'm new to mysql and php and found similar function at http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080717110807AAsXkGL:

However this code compare mysql vs mysql:

3 columns in first table t1: first, last, email. Same columns in t2.

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.email IN (SELECT t2.email from t2)
```

However, I need a PHP code that will delete entire row from MySQL table in column `names` if the names value is present in CSV file in Column A (names).

Thanks in advance for the help! I've already spend good 4 hours looking online and can't find the solution.

Comment: . . Load the data into a temporary table in the database and then use database functions for your operations.

Comment: Mysql supports CSV files as a backend storage if configured for that purpose, but there's no way to setup a db from the CSV file directly. You have to import it by usual means (ie. an external script), so you might as well do it with an efficient db engine and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full answer for those that are seeking:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";

$dbname = "yourdatabase";

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$lines =file('active.csv');
foreach($lines as $line){
$na[]=trim($line);
}

$in=implode(',',$na);


$query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE t2.value IN ($in)";
$del=mysql_query($query,$link);
```

If you want to delete in Table 1 entire row if the value is not present in CSV file then change the query to:

```
    $query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE t2.value NOT IN ($in)";
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: the header in CSV file should NOT be present because otherwise this script will delete entire Table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array `tmpArray` of the result from `SELECT t2.email from t2`

and do something like this:

```
$in = implode(',', $tmpArray);

DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.email IN ($in)
```